# How to create slider same as android inbuilt lock slider?

Tags: android

i need creating slider same as like iphone or android inbuilt lock slider in home screen app. for this functionality i will use  any inbuilt control or create custom layout for this. anyone has info. regarding this than pls send me any link or details.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to make a custom slider:

Use a [seekbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) widget.

Then, on the [onStopTrackingTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html#onStopTrackingTouch%28android.widget.SeekBar%29) listener, reset the seekbar position to ZERO unless the rightmost value has been reached. This will have a "snapping" effect. You can also code an animation to bring it back to the initial position smoothly instead of the "snapping" effect. If the rightmost value has been reached, you can do whatever you wanted to do.

You can use custom 9-patch graphics too!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but how to implement custom seekbar because i need lock slider like inbuilt android lock.

Comment: Use android:thumb <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#attr_android:thumb> and android:progress:drawable <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:progressDrawable>